# remove index.php in url using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

I'm developing an application based on Ubuntu & Apache2 & CodeIgniter

I've a controller named `Site` like this

```
class Site extends CI_Controller {
    public function view($page = 'home')
    {
        $this->load->view('site/'.$page, $data);
    }
}
```

in `application/views/site` I have `home.php` & `about.php`

`localhost/index.php/about` works well
but `localhost/about` gets
`Not Found,The requested URL /about was not found on this server.`

I've already

1. make sure `mod_rewrite` turned on and `AllowOverride All` in apache2 config file.
2. `$config['index_page'] = '';` in `application/config/config.php`

I've also set route to

```
$route['default_controller'] = "site/view";  
$route['404_override'] = '';   
$route['(:any)'] = "site/view/$1";
```

Here's my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]  

<Files "index.php">
AcceptPathInfo On
</Files>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the .htaccess I am using (on Yii, but should be interchangable):

```
RewriteEngine on
# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Almost identical to yours

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow this page about [codeignitor pretty urls](http://www.fahdmurtaza.com/myblog/2008/08/22/codeigniter-clean-urls-apache-mod-rewrite-removing-indexphp-from-url-in-codeigniter-application.html). Your rules look correct, but I'm terrible with regex.

Some things to look into would be checking if mod_rewrite is available by using phpinfo();. Also step three in that link talks about enabling mod_rewrite using a2enmod. And make sure you restart Apache.

Answer (score 0):

from my codeigniter website .

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA] 
</IfModule>
```